# How drawing signature with a pencil effect in objective C ?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, draw

I try to developpe a new app based on drawing effects. I know simple effect, but i have seen some app with a brush effect (pencil effect).

how to do somethink like this ? (SignNow app)

Thanks

You can see some example below. (first with my code and second i want the same effect)

first :

[myapp drawing a signature](http://hangeul.legtux.org/myapp.PNG)

second :

[signnow app i want same](http://hangeul.legtux.org/signnow.PNG)

my code :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Set drawing params
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [self.foreColor CGColor]);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapButt);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextBeginPath(context);




// This flag tells us to move to the point
// rather than draw a line to the point
BOOL isFirstPoint = YES;

// Loop through the strings in the array
// which are just serialized CGPoints
for (NSString *touchString in self.handwritingCoords) {

    // Unserialize
    CGPoint tapLocation = CGPointFromString(touchString);

    // If we have a CGPointZero, that means the next
    // iteration of this loop will represent the first
    // point after a user has lifted their finger.
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(tapLocation, CGPointZero)) {
        isFirstPoint = YES;
        continue;
    }


    // If first point, move to it and continue. Otherwize, draw a line from
    // the last point to this one.
    if (isFirstPoint) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, tapLocation.x, tapLocation.y);




            //CGContextAddArc(ctx, tapLocation.x, tapLocation.y, 30.00, (startDeg-90)*M_PI/180.0, (endDeg-90)*M_PI/180.0, 0);
        isFirstPoint = NO;
    } else {
        CGPoint startPoint = CGContextGetPathCurrentPoint(context);
        CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y, tapLocation.x, tapLocation.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, tapLocation.x, tapLocation.y);
    }

}   

// Stroke it, baby!
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to get some inspiration on the active [smooth-drawing](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/smooth-drawing) project. That's an excellent place to begin and learn the best practices. Besides you can learn more about the thinking behind this project on the great article [drawing smooth lines with cocos2d](http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/).